# Dismiss Snackbar Onclick of React Alert component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, snackjs

I have a React Snackbar component that I have called in a parent component and I passed props based on the severity, message and open to the Snackbar component. I am able to access the props in the child Snackbar component. However, when dismissing the Snackbar or trying to close it, I get the error `TypeError: setOpen is not a function`.

```
 export default function MessageSnackbars(props) {
 const classes = useStyles();
 const [setOpen] = React.useState(false);
 const message = props.message;
 const severity = props.severity;
 const open = props.open;

 const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
    return;
 }

setOpen(false);
};

return (
<div className={classes.root}>
  <Snackbar
    autoHideDuration={6000}
    onClose={handleClose}
    open={open}
  >
    <Alert
      onClose={handleClose}
      severity={severity}
    >
      {message}
    </Alert>
  </Snackbar>
</div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item in the array is the state and the second item is the state updater function.

So

```
const [setOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

is supposed to be

```
const [ ,setOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

Also you are relying on the `open` from the props, to handle the state of the snackbar component ( open/close ). So unless the props.open is updated in the parent, it would not really close the component.

One other way would be is to keep the `props.open` in sync within the component which would work as expected.

```
export default function MessageSnackbars(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {message, severity, open} = props;
  // Uses props.open to keep track of the open state 
  const [isLocalOpen, setIsLocalOpen] = React.useState(open);

  // Used to keep the props.open in sync
  // as part of the local state
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLocalOpen(open);
  }, [open]);

  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }

    setIsLocalOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Snackbar autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose} open={isLocalOpen}>
        <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity={severity}>
          {message}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This resolves the error but does not close or dismiss the Snackbar. Any help to close the Snackbar will be appreciated.

Comment: This is well understood. You keep the current state of the Snackbar in the same component and update it when necessarry.

Comment: correct. That way you can manage the state of the snackbar. If you don't want to do it, then you will have to call the method on the parent who is the owner of `open` which will update the state

Comment: Then in this case what happens is that once you dismiss the snackbar and you make a request again without refreshing the browser, the Snackbar wont show unless you refresh the browser. So the most effective way is to let the parent who is the owner update the state.

Comment: I have been trying all night to go by the second approach in order to get the Snackbar showing multiple times and not only once. Any codes to help me handle the state from the parent will be much appreciated. @Sushanth

Comment: Instead of calling `setIsLocalOpen(false);` , call a method passed in as a  prop.  `props.onClose()` . Then you can get rid of the useState in the component and use the `open` from `props.open` directly